# How to get Oauth_verifier in implementation of likedIn in my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can anyone suggest to  me for how to get oauth_verifier for linkedIn api call..
I have  stuck for it. Please give me ideas. because i read a lot at linkedIn API but don't get 
exactly what will i do for getting oauth_verifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this below link

To get API key from below link
http://developer.linkedin.com/rest

To get demo from below link this will help you.
https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1559
```

Comment: thanks for it but i want ouath_ verifier..give some idea of finding oauth_ verifer.